# El addEventListener no me funciona ni tampoco se guardan los datos en el localStorage

Tags: javascript, eventos, local-storage

intento hacer que funcione el código pero nada, ciertas partes del código que escribo si lo toma pero menos el addEventListener y lo de que los objetos no se guardan en el localStorage, revise el código mil veces y no encuentro el error, me fije que este todo bien escrito, que este todo vinculado, en la consola no aparece ningún error ya no se que hacer :(

```
function renderizarTabla(alumnos) {
    const bodyTabla = document.getElementById("body_alumnos");

    // limpio body de la tabla
    bodyTabla.innerHTML = "";

    for (const alumno of alumnos) {
        const tr = document.createElement("tr");

        const td1 = document.createElement("td");
        td1.innerText = alumnos.nombre;

        const td2 = document.createElement("td");
        td2.innerText = alumnos.materia;

        tr.append(td1);
        tr.append(td2);

        // agregar tr al body
        bodyTabla.append(tr);
    }
};

let alumnos = [];

// chequeo si tengo alumnos en el localStorage
const alumnosStorage = localStorage.getItem("alumnos");

if (alumnosStorage != null) {
    alumnos = JSON.parse(alumnosStorage);
};

const formularioAgregarAlumnos = document.getElementById("formulario_agregar_alumnos");

formularioAgregarAlumnos.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDeFault();

    // obtengo el nombre y la materia a rendir
    const inputNombreAlumno = document.getElementById("nombre_alumno");
    const inputMateriaARendir = document.getElementById("materia_a_rendir");

    const nombreAlumno = inputNombreAlumno.value;
    const materiaARendir = inputMateriaARendir.value;

    // agrego alumnos al array y luego al localStorage
    alumnos.push({
        nombre: nombreAlumno,
        materia: materiaARendir,
    });

    localStorage.setItem("alumnos", JSON.stringify(alumnos));

    // renderizar tabla
    renderizarTabla(alumnos)
})

console.log(tr)
```

Comment: Agrega el html para hacer pruebas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de revisar tu código y armar un playground pude identificar los errores que tiene tu código:

Error 1:
En el listener de submit del formulario llamas a la función `preventDefault` de la manera incorrecta (la letra F esta en mayúscula):

Modificar esto:

```
e.preventDeFault();
```

por esto:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Error 2:
En el `for` que itera sobre el listado de alumnos accedes de manera incorrecta a la información del alumno ya que lo haces sobre el array y no sobre el objeto por ende te va a marcar undefined todas las celdas de tu tabla:

Modificar esto:

```
td1.innerText = alumnos.nombre;
td2.innerText = alumnos.materia;
```

por esto

```
td1.innerText = alumno.nombre;
td2.innerText = alumno.materia;
```

Y aca te dejo el código completo:

```
function renderizarTabla(alumnos) {
  const bodyTabla = document.getElementById("body_alumnos");
    console.log(alumnos)
  // limpio body de la tabla
  bodyTabla.innerHTML = "";

  for (const alumno of alumnos) {
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  
    const td1 = document.createElement("td");
    
    td1.innerText = alumno.nombre;
  
    const td2 = document.createElement("td");
    td2.innerText = alumno.materia;
  
    tr.append(td1);
    tr.append(td2);
  
    // agregar tr al body
    bodyTabla.append(tr);
  }
};

let alumnos = [];

// chequeo si tengo alumnos en el localStorage
const alumnosStorage = localStorage.getItem("alumnos");

if (alumnosStorage != null) {
  alumnos = JSON.parse(alumnosStorage);
}

const formularioAgregarAlumnos = document.getElementById("formulario_agregar_alumnos");

formularioAgregarAlumnos.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // obtengo el nombre y la materia a rendir
  const inputNombreAlumno = document.getElementById("nombre_alumno");
  const inputMateriaARendir = document.getElementById("materia_a_rendir");
  

  const nombreAlumno = inputNombreAlumno.value;
  const materiaARendir = inputMateriaARendir.value;
  
  // agrego alumnos al array y luego al localStorage
 alumnos.push({
    nombre: nombreAlumno,
    materia: materiaARendir,
  });
  
  localStorage.setItem("alumnos", JSON.stringify(alumnos));
  
  // renderizar tabla
  renderizarTabla(alumnos)
})
```

Saludos!